# How can I make the program wait for an interaction in nextcord?

Tags: python, button, async-await, interaction, nextcord

I would like when a person clicks the button, the code starts from if player1! = player2. But once bet 1000 is written the code is all executed and does not wait for the button to be pressed to confirm player 2

```
class Counter(nextcord.ui.View):

    #THIS IS WHAT HAPPEN WHEN A PLAYER CLICK THE BUTTON
    @nextcord.ui.button(label='Join the bet', style=nextcord.ButtonStyle.green)
    async def count(self, button: nextcord.ui.Button, interaction: nextcord.Interaction):
      button.disabled = True
      player2 = interaction.user
      button.label = 'Bet closed'
      with open("opponent", "w") as f:
        f.write(str(player2))
      print(player2)
      await interaction.response.edit_message(view=self)


    #THIS IS THE LISTEN OF THE COMMAND BET (AMOUNT)
    @client.listen()
    async def on_message(message):
      if message.content.startswith('bet'):
        player1 = message.author
        with open("opponent", "w") as f:
          f.write(str(player1))
        with open("opponent", "r") as f:
          player2 = str(f.read())
        x = message.content.split(" ")
        bet = int(x[1])
        try:
          with open("Players/"+str(message.author.id), "x") as f:
            money = 1000
        except:
          with open("Players/"+str(message.author.id), "r") as f:
            money = int(f.read())
        try:
          r=random.randint(1,100)
          if bet<=money and bet>0:
            player1 = str(player1)
            await message.channel.send(message.author.mention +  " is waiting for a player...", view=Counter())
            print(player1)
            print(player2)
            #check = player1 != player2 THIS DON'T WORK
            #await client.wait_for('interaction', check=check) THIS DON'T WORK
            if player2 != player1: 
              print(player2)
              if r%2==0:
                money = money + bet
                with open("Players/"+str(message.author.id), "w") as file:
                  file.write(str(money))
                await message.channel.send(message.author.mention + " won " + str(bet)+ "\n($" + str(money) + ").")
                    
              else:
                money = money - bet   
                with open("Players/"+str(message.author.id), "w") as file:
                  file.write(str(money))
                await message.channel.send(message.author.mention + " lost " + str(bet)+ "\n($" + str(money) + ").")
            else:
                 with open("opponent", "r") as f:
                   player2 = str(f.read())


                    
          else:
            await message.channel.send(message.author.mention + " you don't have enough money. You only have ($" + str(money) + ").")
                
        except ValueError:
            await message.channel.send(message.author.mention + " wrong value.")
```

I tried using a while and looping if player1! = player2 so that when a player clicks the button the code should start. But since the button is an AWAIT it never updates and it doesn't work as the while loops the code

another problem is that I'm using the files because from what I have seen GLOBAL does not work and I can't bring the variables between functions. for example interaction.user

Answer (score 0):

Put [`interaction.response.defer`](https://nextcord.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#nextcord.InteractionResponse.defer) at the top of your button's code.
 It ask discord to wait for your `interaction.response` since the default response time for bots is 3 seconds only.

```py
@nextcord.ui.button(label='Join the bet', style=nextcord.ButtonStyle.green)
async def count(self, button: nextcord.ui.Button, interaction: nextcord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.defer(with_message=True,ephemeral=True)
    #do your stuff here
```

Comment: hello thank you very much. i added the code but it keeps giving me the same problem. (I'm sure something stupid is missing in the program) Can I add you on discord for a hand? If you can help me I would like to give you credit for the development. my discord is Galoka # 6482

Comment: Sorry recently I'm busy with my school activities. You can go to the `#help` channel in Nextcord official channel https//discord.gg/nextcord to ask for support in code. Hope this can help you and happy coding :D